# Trouble connecting a small network.. pinging

Tags: troubleshooting, ping

RTR configuration:

```
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname T-RTR
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$g2ly$xT6VHT1gXBTLuXp6uJlp./
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
cts logging verbose
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FGL1943200R
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 172.16.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 172.16.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 no auto-summary
 passive-interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
banner motd ^C Unauthorized Access is prohibited!^C
!
```

Network topology: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_gP-IlJx8dsN1BCTElKa1gwMmIySVdKYVp3Q3pRdXpfM3dv

BR: it's an RV320 if you guys need some info let me know. It's running DHCP to provide IP addresses to the attached routers.

Here's my problem.

<s>I cannot ping from any host on the `172.16.x.x` network to my BR interface `192.168.1.1`.</s> - FIXED

<s>I cannot ping from my BR to RTR g0/1 interface (Where intervlan routing is).</s> - FIXED

I cannot ping from any of my hosts to the `internet` or my `WAN` interface on BR (`192.168.13.81/24` with `gateway 192.168.13.254`)

All of my Internal LAN can ping each other.

`RTR` can ping `192.168.13.81`, `Internet`,`192.168.13.254` and `192.168.1.1` (pretty much everything).

i ran debug ICMP on RTR, then tried to ping from BR to int g0/1.x (subinterfaces) on RTR but i get nothing on the debug.

My BR has RIPv2 enabled.

RTR Routing Table:

```
Gateway of last resort is 192.168.1.1 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [254/0] via 192.168.1.1
      172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 2 masks
R        172.16.1.0/24 [120/2] via 192.168.1.1, 00:00:03, GigabitEthernet0/0
C        172.16.10.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.10
L        172.16.10.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.10
C        172.16.20.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.20
L        172.16.20.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.20
C        172.16.30.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.30
L        172.16.30.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1.30
R        172.16.60.0/24 [120/2] via 192.168.1.1, 00:00:03, GigabitEthernet0/0
      192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        192.168.1.2/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
R     192.168.13.0/24 [120/1] via 192.168.1.1, 00:00:03, GigabitEthernet0/0
```

Comment: I added version 2 to rip and passive interface g0/1. All hosts have firewall turned off for now.

Comment: First, you are ***not*** running RIPv2 on the router since you are missing the `version 2` command from RIP.

Comment: Why are you using DHCP to assign `G0/0`? You are probably better off specifically assigning the address since you probably never want it to change. Using DHCP for infrastructure interfaces in you LAN is not really a good idea.

Comment: I think you need to include the BR configuration, too.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely that the BR has not route to your 172.16.0.0/16 network so cannot send any response.

You could NAT all traffic coming from your network in 172.16.0.0/16 to your 'external' IP address : 192.168.1.2.

If your network is actually routable within the school lan without NAT, then you must ensure your rip configuration is working.
(as said by Ron, first add "version 2" in rip configuration)

Comment: You are probably correct that the BR has a routing problem, but that is going to be something to do with the RIP configuration. Double-NAT will cause all kinds of problems. I'm not sure that is really appropriate in this situation.

Comment: You're right of course, I suggested NAT since it is connected to a school lan, that will likely not be configured to to allow this network, or NAT it to the internet, but cannot know this for sure.

Comment: I added 172.16.0.0/16 route to BR, and now i can ping.. still trying to go online on my hosts though. thanks.. i thought RIP would share the routing info from RTR and pass it to BR.

Comment: @user1986245, you seem to have a problem with the RIP configuration on BR. You didn't include the configuration for it, so we have no way to tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have attached a photo.. i cant add more due to low rep

Comment: Your problem may be related to using broadcast on RIPv2 on BR. RIPv2 normally uses multicast, but RIPv1 uses broadcast. It may be that BR is ignoring the RIPv2 multicasts from RTR because it is set to use broadcast.

Comment: Cool! switched it, erased the static routes, and it still pings internally.. however, i cant ping from host to `192.168.13.81` (WAN int) or `internet`

Comment: Are there any networks in the school LAN which duplicate the network addresses you are using? This could cause problems with return traffic from the school LAN or the Internet. The school LAN needs to know that those routes exist, and how to get to them. That would be statically configured, or through a routing protocol like RIP.

Comment: will this cause a problem with me being able to access the WAN interface on my br? i set it to `192.168.13.81`, my rtr can ping it but not my hosts..